# Cake pattern w/ akka: Providing implicit actorSystem to several layers

Tags: scala, akka, cake-pattern

I'm currently baking my first cake pattern, so please bear with me.

I took my working monolithic app and I cutted it into functional layers. The cut looks clean but resulted in two of the layers that depend on an implicit ActorSystem.

I tried to solve this dependency like this:

```
trait LayerA {
  this: ActorSystemProvider =>
  private implicit val implicitActorSystem = actorSystem
  import implicitActorSystem.dispatcher // implicit execution ctx
  ...
}
```

... and similarly for LayerX

My assembly class looks like:

```
class Assembly extends LayerA with LayerB with LayerX with ActorSystemProvider
```

where ActorSystemProvider simply instantiates the actor system.

This does not work given that the `ActorSystem` does not exist when the dependencies are resolved and the val's are instantiated, resulting in a NPE.  This also looks really ugly and I'm sure there has to be a nicer/easier way to deal with it.

How should I deal with shared implicit dependencies among layers when using the cake pattern, like `ActorSystem` in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Self types is not a requirement for building a caked architecture, actually i use self types only in cases when a trait is a component of a layer. So when i need to place some implicit into the scope (for example ActorRefFactory for Spray Client) i just mix a trait in :

```
trait ActorSystemProvider {
  implicit def actorSystem: ActorSystem
}
```

And on the lowest layer (so called "end of the world") i have the following code structure:

```
trait ServiceStack
  extends SomeModule
     with SomeModule2
     with SomeModule3 
     with ActorSystemProvider 

object ServiceLauncher extends App with ServiceStack {
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ServiceName")
}
```

It's an oversimplified example (if you want a great example of a real system build on top of a Cake Pattern then you should definitely take a look at the [Precog](https://github.com/slamdata/platform) system, [example](https://github.com/slamdata/platform/blob/master/mimir/src/main/scala/com/precog/mimir/StdLib.scala#L274) where different modules/layers connects), but not you can mix implicit ActorSystem when you need it.

Comment: @Alexv I don't understand where you reference `ActorSystemProvider` - how do I access then the `actorSystem` from an internal trait like `myInternalCalculator` it is used deep in the call hierarchy.

Comment: @Jas It looks like it should be `with ActorSystemProvider` instead of `ActorRefProvider`. Then you can init it in something similar to `ServiceLauncher`

Answer (score 5):

If you can instantiate the vals lazily rather than eagerly, you can make the implicitActorSystem a lazy val instead of a val. So it only gets executed when it is accessed the first time. I think this should solve the problem of NPE. 
(Another little known interesting fact posted by @ViktorKlang FYI: If the initialization of a lazy val throws an exception, it will attempt to reinitialize the val at next access.)

Another way would be to make each of your methods which need execution context accept an implicit executionContext like:

```
trait LayerA {
  def getUser(id: Int)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) = {
    ...
  }
}
```